# Perform HTTP POST with libcurl - digest authentication, using curl_easy_send\ curl_easy_recv

Tags: c++, linux, libcurl, http-post, digest-authentication

I'm trying to write a simple program which uses libcurl to perform HTTP POST using digest authentication.

It works fine when I'm setting the XML buffer that I want to send using appropriate `curlopt_easy_setopt` calls with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` and then calling `curl_easy_perform`.

However, when I try to connect after setting `CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY` to 1, and then using `curl_easy_send` - the return code (for the send call) is `CURLE_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL`.

(Of course, the username, password and digest authentication scheme are set successfully before).

Using a sniffer, it is obvious to see that the digest negotiation is not performed at all.

How can I still use `curl_easy_send`\ `curl_easy_recv` with `CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY`, but let libcurl to perform the digest negotiation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is impossible after all.

`curl_easy_send` and `curl_easy_recv` are intended for implementing custom protocols.

Thus, what I think is happening is that the normal HTTP protocol handling that libcurl would be doing for `curl_easy_perform` is not being done at all, so there is no digest\ NTLM\ GSS negotiation available.

Hope that it will help someone.